# Why Changeset.change is skipping validation in Elixir?

Tags: validation, elixir, ecto, changeset

This is a simple function used to insert or update some data.
If user data is already in db i simply update it, otherwise i insert a new row with data. Everything works fine but i have a problem with validation.
Changeset definition:

```
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name, :surname, :user_id])
    |> validate_required([:name, :surname, :user_id])
    |> unique_constraint(:user_id)
  end
```

validate_required is currently working only during insert and not during update.

```
  def add_or_change(user_id, new_data) do
    data_from_db = data_by_user_id (user_id)
    case data_from_db do
      nil ->
        Data.changeset(%Data{}, new_data)
        |> Repo.insert()

      _ ->
        Changeset.change(data_from_db, new_data)
        |> Repo.update()
    end
  end
```

If i try to insert "" as :name value, i get an error (can't be blank) as expected. However if i'm updating an existing row with "" as :name value, changeset does not pass through validation and my db is updated improperly. How to force validation also on change, before Repo.update()??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc: [`Ecto.Changeset/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#change/2) is meant for internal data changes, so it bypasses validations:

> The function is meant for working with data internal to the application. Because of that neither validation nor casting is performed. This means `change/2` expects the keys in the changes map or keyword to be atoms.

You should use [`Ecto.Changeset.cast/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast/4) to apply the validations, and then update if it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this:

```
    Changeset.change(data_from_db, new_data)
```

Just run the same function you were already using:

```
    Data.changeset(data_from_db, new_data)
```

---

By the way, you can actually simplify this function a lot:

```
  def add_or_change(user_id, new_data) do
    (data_by_user_id(user_id) || %Data{})
    |> Data.changeset(new_data)
    |> Repo.insert_or_update()
  end
```